# setFormula then get and set Value - is this the best way?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a growing dataset on a google sheet with which I need to run some complex filters/queries/vlookups on. However I only need to do this daily as the new data arrives. The number of complex formulas is starting to slow the spreadsheet to a grinding halt, particularly with our woeful broadband connection.!

I therefore came up with a workaround of using GAS to set the formula in a cell, then to get the Value and then to set the Value, knowing that GAS doesn't run the spreadsheet functions natively (as per VBA). As I have already worked up the filters and vlookups on the sheets I need, I didn't go into scripting the formulas to achieve the same thing.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rng = sh.getRange('B11');
  rng.setFormula('=sum(filter(C2:E5,A2:A5="Bob"))');
  var val = rng.getValue();
  rng.setValue(val);
}
```

In my production spreadsheet I can have @ 300 formulas on each of 30 sheets, so if these are all pinging away at the dataset I get lengthy periods of the grey progress bar. (In essence the formulas are filtering/summing or counting daily data to weekly data) My example above shows everything happening on one sheet.

Wondered if there was a better/different way of doing this?

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Can you share an example of your data? What is your end goal with this script?

Comment: End goal is to summarise the base data. It would be difficult to provide example data as it would require hundreds of rows to be meaningful. I will try though.

Comment: There are @ 1000 entries per month. Columns contain: Name, Date, Behaviour, Frequency. These must be summarised by Name, then by week (so combine all entries with a date in a week), by Behaviour, then the sum of the Frequency. My current formula for this is: `code`=iferror(sum(filter(database!$H$3:$H,database!$G$3:$G=N$2,database!$A$3:$A=$A$1,database!$B$3:$B>=$A446,database!$B$3:$B<$A447)),""). Repeat in @ 800 cells on 30 sheets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have not come up with anything better so will post my solution. Two scripts. First one checks that the user actually want to update their values, if they say yes, then checks with the user again and shows them the date range it will update. Then runs the second script, which in simple terms just applies a formula to a cell then copies the value generated and pastes the value. On testing with full data load, spreadsheet does no "waiting/progress grey box" at all so solves my issue.

```
function runWriteBehavs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sy = ss.getSheetByName("summary");
  //gets last row in column B - data is contigious
  var BVals = sy.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var BLast = BVals.filter(String).length;
  var rowBeh = BLast + 1;
  var lastDate = sy.getRange("A" + rowBeh).getValue();
  var lastEndDate = new Date(lastDate.getTime()+6*3600000*24);;
  //formats dates
  lastDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(lastDate), "GB", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  lastEndDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(lastEndDate), "GB", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  //message box for confirmation
  var output = Browser.msgBox("This script will run the summaries for the week:\\n" + lastDate + " - " + lastEndDate + "\\n Are you really sure you want to continue?",Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);

  if ( output == "yes" ) {
    //calls main update script
    writeBehavs();
  }

}


//Needs to be run once all data is entered
function writeBehavs() {
  //get variables
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var db = ss.getSheetByName("database");
  var sy = ss.getSheetByName("summary");
  var sL = ss.getSheetByName("lists");
  //gets number of behaviours, a counta() of list on sheet
  var bCount = sL.getRange("H1").getValue();
  //gets column listing hard coded on sheet
  var bCol = sL.getRange("H2:H30").getValues();
  //gets last row in column B - data is contigious
  var BVals = sy.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var BLast = BVals.filter(String).length;

  //for each number on behaviour count
  for (var i=0; i<bCount; ++i) {
  //set the column
  var colBeh = [bCol[i]];
  //set the correct row for data entry and start date check
  var rowBeh = BLast + 1;
  //sets correct row for end date check
  var rowBeh2 = rowBeh + 1;

  //gets first empty row in Column from iteration
  var rng = sy.getRange(colBeh+rowBeh);
  //enters the formula in the cell
  rng.setFormula('=iferror(sum(filter(database!$E$2:$E,database!$D$2:$D='+ colBeh + '$1,database!$A$2:$A=lists!$G$2,database!$B$2:$B>=$A' + rowBeh + ',database!$B$2:$B<$A' + rowBeh2 + ')),"0")');
  //captures the value generated by the formula
  var val = rng.getValue();
  //pastes the formula to the cell
  rng.setValue(val);
  //Job Done!
  }

}
```